# REDCap Data quality considering repeating instruments forms

Tags: redcap

Is it possible to create data quality rules for repeated instruments fields?
I was able to do it but since I do not specify that it is a repeated instrument, when the rule is broken, two queries appear, one has the information of the nonrepeatable instruments' fields and the other regarding the repeated instrument.

Rule:

```
[1_screening_arm_1][scr_med]<>'' and [1_screening_arm_1][screening_complete]='2' and [1_screening_arm_1][concmed_yn]<>'' and [1_screening_arm_1][concomitant_medication_complete]='2' and [1_screening_arm_1][scr_med]='1' and [1_screening_arm_1][concmed_yn]='0'
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question.
The page from SMPH Research Informatics (https://kb.wisc.edu/smph/informatics/page.php?id=88571) indicates that you need to specify the event, variable, and repeat number. If you are referencing the second instance of a repeating event, for example, you would use the format [event][variable][2].
I tried this method, but the specified repeat number did not have any effect. It might be a bug.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).